# Unit tests that need more than one WebServiceMock

Tags: unit-test, callout, json, httpcalloutmock

I'm dealing with an odd situation where I need to call Webservice A to authenticate to Webservice B and Webservice C, all with different endpoints. I know how to setup [mocks](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm) to test B and C individually, but I can't do that for my real tests. The workflow is:

1. User loads a VF page
2. On load, VF page calls B.someMethod()
3. B.someMethod needs to first call A.getAuthToken()
4. Use authToken to complete call to B.someMethod()

I know that I could create one mock class to handle all of the web services (or at least to fake the authentication), but that could be very cumbersome to maintain given that B and C both have dozens of methods.

Is there a better way to handle unit tests where each method needs to provide a mock for multiple endpoints?

**Note:** These are JSON-based web services, and not SOAP.

Comment: How about using instanceof on the 'stub' parameter passed into the doInvoke? e.g. if stub instanceof A then delegate to a mock function for A else if stub instanceof B then delegate to mock function for B

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; could you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: Sure, have added an answer.

Comment: Wouldn't MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock handle this scenario? https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_static.htm

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The **doInvoke** method on the mock interface passes in the **stub** and **request** parameters. You can use these to condition to dispatch the mock logic to various other mock implementations, while only registering a single mock implementation.

```
Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new MockDispatcher());

public class MockDispatcher implements WebServiceMock 
{
    public void doInvoke(
        Object stub, Object request, Map<String, Object> response,
        String endpoint, String soapAction, String requestName,
        String responseNS, String responseName, String responseType) 
    {
        if(stub instanceof A)
            new AMock().doInvoke(
                stub, request, response, 
                endpoint, soapAction, requestName, 
                responseNS, responseName, responseType);
        else if(stub instanceof B)
            new BMock().doInvoke(
                stub, request, response, 
                endpoint, soapAction, requestName, 
                responseNS, responseName, responseType);
        return;
    }
}    

public class AMock 
{
    public void doInvoke(
        Object stub, Object request, Map<String, Object> response,
        String endpoint, String soapAction, String requestName,
        String responseNS, String responseName, String responseType) 
    {
        if(request instanceof A.GetAuthTokenRequest_element)
            response.put('response_x', new A.GetAuthTokenResponse_element());
        return;
    }
}    

public class BMock 
{
    public void doInvoke(
        Object stub, Object request, Map<String, Object> response,
        String endpoint, String soapAction, String requestName,
        String responseNS, String responseName, String responseType) 
    {
        if(request instanceof B.SomeMethodRequest_element)
            response.put('response_x', new B.SomeMethodResponse_element());
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach and will look into it in more detail; I hadn't seen doInvoke in Apex before.

Comment: I forgot to specify that I'm working with JSON web services, but I think I can adapt the dispatcher pattern by examining the request object.

Comment: Thank you for this! It worked great for me. I had some weird generated code that I had to work through but once I got through it, this fit the bill perfectly! Thanks @AndrewFawcett

Answer (score 6):

I've found I've had to add something like this in my actual Class methods to switch my testMock if I'm running a test.

```java
public String getActivityFile() {
    if(test.isRunningTest) {
        Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.clas, new WebserviceNumber2Mock());
    }
    return new WebserviceNumber2().getActivityFile();
}
```

---

**Update 2018-05-22**

Extending this idea, it's a pain to deal with circular references when referencing a Test class in a Production class.  However, you can references a Test Class `Type` without causing a direct reference to another class.  As of today (API 42.0), Types are not compiled when saving Apex.  So you can do something like the following:

```java
public abstract class SoapApi {

    public interface Request {
        Type getType();
        Type getResponseType();
        Type getMockResponseType();
        String getSoapAction();
        String getRequestNamespace();
        String getResponseNamespace();
        String getResponseName();
    }

    public abstract class MockResponse implements WebServiceMock {

        // Abstract
        public abstract Object getResponse(Request request);

        protected Object response;

        // WebServiceMock
        public void doInvoke(
            Object stub,
            Object request,
            Map<String, Object> response,
            String endpoint,
            String soapAction,
            String requestName,
            String responseNamespace,
            String responseName,
            String responseType
        ) {
            if(!(request instanceof Request)) {
                new InvalidMockRequestException(System.Label.SoapApi_InvalidMockRequestException); // 'Requestable must implement SoapApi.Requestable'
            }
            this.response = this.getResponse((Request) request);
            response.put('response_x', this.response);
        }
    }

    // Abstract
    public abstract String getEndpoint();

    // Instance
    public Object send(SoapApi.Request request) {
        if(request == null) {
            throw new NullRequestException(System.Label.SoapApi_NullRequestException); // 'Request cannot be null'
        }
        if(request.getType() == null) {
            throw new NullRequestTypeException(System.Label.SoapApi_NullRequestTypeException); // 'Request\'s Type cannot be null'
        }

        if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
            Object response = request.getMockResponseType() == null ? null : request.getMockResponseType().newInstance();
            if(!(response instanceof MockResponse)) {
                throw new InvalidMockResponseException(System.Label.SoapApi_InvalidMockResponseException); // 'Request\'s Mock Response Type must extend SoapApi.MockResponse'
            }
            Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, response);
        }

        // Invoke WebServiceCallout
        Map<String, Object> responses = new Map<String, Object> {
            'response_x' => null
        };

        try {
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request,
                responses,
                new String[] {
                    this.getEndpoint(),
                    request.getSoapAction(),
                    request.getRequestNamespace(),
                    request.getRequestName(),
                    request.getResponseNamespace(),
                    request.getResponseName(),
                    request.getResponseType().getName()
                }
            );
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // Can do debugging here else remove the Try/Catach
            throw e;
        }

        return responses.get('response_x');
    }
}
```

---

```java
public with sharing class ThirdPartyData {

    public with sharing class LocationRequest implements SoapApi.Request {
        public String address;
        @TestVisible String[] address_type_info = new String[] {/* ... */};

        @TestVisible String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[] {/*...*/};
        @TestVisible String[] field_order_type_info = new String[] {
            'address'
        };

        // SoapApi.Request
        public Type getType() {
            return ThirdPartyData.LocationRequest.class;
        }

        public Type getResponseType() {
            return return ThirdPartyData.LocationResponse.class;
        }

        public Type getMockResponseType() {
            return return ThirdPartyDataMock.LocationResponse.class;
        }

        public String getSoapAction() {
            return String.join(
                new String[] {
                    'https://api.example.com', 
                    'ThirdPartData', 
                    'getLocation'
                }, 
                '/'
            );
        }

        public String getRequestNamespace() {
            return 'ThirdPartyData';
        }

        public String getResponseNamespace() {
            return 'ThirdPartyData';
        }

        public String getResponseName() {
            return 'LocationResponse';
        }
    }

    public with sharing class LocationResponse {
        public String address, city, state, postal;
        @TestVisible String[] address_type_info = new String[] {/* ... */};
        @TestVisible String[] city_type_info = new String[] {/* ... */};
        @TestVisible String[] state_type_info = new String[] {/* ... */};
        @TestVisible String[] postal_type_info = new String[] {/* ... */};

        @TestVisible String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[] { /*...*/};
        @TestVisible String[] field_order_type_info = new String[] {
            'address', 
            'city', 
            'state', 
            'postal'
        };
    }

    // Instance
    public with sharing class Api extends SoapApi {

        public Integer timeout_x = 60000; // Milliseconds
        public String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[] {
            'https://api.example.com', 'ThirdPartData',
        };
        public Map<String, String> inputHttpHeaders_x;

        public Api() {
            super();
        }

        // SoapApi
        public override String getEndpoint() {
            return 'callout:packagenamepace__ThirdPartData/Api.svc';
        }

        public LocationResponse getLocation(String address) {
            LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
            {
                request.address = address;
            }
            return (LocationResponse) this.send(request);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```java
@IsTest
public with sharing class ThirdPartyDataMock {

    public with sharing class InvalidMockRequestException extends Exception {}

    public with sharing class LocationResponse extends SoapApi.MockResponse {
        public override Object getResponse(SoapiApi.Request request) {
            if(!(request instanceof ThirdPartyData.LocationRequest)) {
                throw new InvalidMockRequestException(String.format(
                    System.Label.ThirdPartyDataMock_InvalidMockRequestException, // '{0} only supports {1}'
                    new String[] {
                        ThirdPartyDataMock.LocationResponse.class.getName(), 
                        ThirdPartyData.LocationRequest.class.getName()
                    }
                ));
            }

            ThirdPartyData.LocationRequest locationRequest = (ThirdPartyData.LocationRequest) request;

            ThirdPartyData.LocationResponse response = new ThirdPartyData.LocationResponse();
            {
                response.address = address;
                response.city = 'Anytown';
                response.state = 'MI';
                response.postal = '49000';
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hadn't even thought of that approach. It'd allow me to have separate mocks, which is good. Nice idea.

Answer (score 4):

I saw this technique from Andrew a little while back, and it has been a lifesaver for testing complex WebServices. One addition to his answer is that I set the response directly in the mock class e.g.

```
if(request instanceof MyWebService.GetService_element) {
    MyWebService.GetServiceResponse_element testresponse_x = new MyWebService.GetServiceResponse_element();

    testresponse_x.GetServiceResult = MyMockTestResponses_TESTS.getTestValues();
    response.put('response_x', testresponse_x);
}
```

Where GetService is the method in the WebService and MyMockTestResponses.getTestValues() is a returning a static JSON/XML/String that has been set previously in my test classes.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a generic mock generator class to handle all my mock generation.

Its not perfect, but it has handled every scenario I've come across, including this one.

```
//Author: Charlie Jonas 
// Description:  Class is use for creating mock http callouts in test methods. 
// See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm
// for info on how to use class.

@isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
    private static final String DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = 'text/xml';

    //require properites
    private Map<String,String> responseMap = new Map<String,String>();  

    //optional
    public String method { get; set;}

    //optional
    public String contentType { get; set;}
    {contentType = DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE;}

    //optional 
    public Integer statusCode {get; set;}
    //defaults to success
    {statusCode = 200;}

    //optional 
    public Boolean ignoreQuery {get; set;}
    //defaults to success
    {ignoreQuery = true;}


    public MockHttpResponseGenerator(){}

    public MockHttpResponseGenerator(String endpoint, String response){
        addResp(endpoint,response);
    }

    //add an additional endpoint response pairs
    public void addResponse(String endpoint, String response){
        addResp(endpoint,response);
    }

    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        // Optionally, only send a mock response for a specific endpoint
        // and method.
        String endpoint = req.getEndpoint();
        if(ignoreQuery){
            endpoint = getBaseUrl(endpoint);
        }
        String response = responseMap.get(endpoint);
        System.assertNotEquals(response, null);

        if(method != null){
            System.assertEquals(method, req.getMethod());
        }

        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
        res.setBody(response);
        res.setStatusCode(statusCode);
        return res;
    }

    private void addResp(String endpoint, String response){
        if(ignoreQuery){
            endpoint = getBaseUrl(endpoint);
        }
        responseMap.put(endpoint, response);
    }

    private String getBaseUrl(String endpoint){
        Url baseUrl = new URL(endpoint);
        return baseUrl.getHost() + baseUrl.getPath();
    }

}
```

Testing multiple endpoints with 1 mock:

```
MockHttpResponseGenerator mockResponse = new MockHttpResponseGenerator();
mockResponse.addResponse(testEndpoint1, testResponseString1);
mockResponse.addResponse(testEndpoint2, testResponseString2);
```

**There are some limitations**.  All endpoints must currently require the same "options" (Method, Content Type, etc).  I have plans to support setting these in each "response", but I haven't come across the need for it yet.  Will update this post if I ever do.