# How to test a http calls from a second class func call from within first class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have an apex class A. I'm calling the function of B class from within A.

```
class A{

B bobj=new B();

B.function2();


function1();

}
```

This function1 and function2 are http calls to 2 diff rest services.

I wrote a test class with httpcallmockouts for the both function1 and function2.
So the order goes like this inside APex Test class-

```
B objB=new B();

HttpResponse res = CalloutB.getInfoFromExternalService();

A objA=new A();

HttpResponse res = CalloutA.getInfoFromExternalService();


//Till this point my test runs successfully for http calls mock

Test.startTest();

   objA.function1();//Here I get an error http callout not supported for test methods for function2 of B class.

//If I change the order above to 

//A objA=new A();

//HttpResponse res = CalloutA.getInfoFromExternalService();

//B objB=new B();

//HttpResponse res = CalloutB.getInfoFromExternalService();

//Then I get error http callout not supported for test methods for function1 of A class.

Test.stopTest();
```

So, how do you test the http call from within another's class function calls in the first class.

Comment: Have you looked at his blog https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/testing-apex-callouts-using-httpcalloutmock.html .Specially testing multiple callouts section ?

Comment: Yes, I did and I have another test class implementation having http callouts completely and it works fine.

Comment: Only for the above case where i reference another class' func having http callout, the tests fail. For some reason when I change the order of how I add mock callouts for A and B, the fail reason differs in the logs. If A mocks are above B and then I run tests for class A under Test.Start(), then I get error on B's func call. If B mocks are above A's and then I run tests for class A under Test.Start(), then I get error on A's func call in the test class. I can add my code here too if that helps. Do you have any example of http callouts when both A and B class ->functions have http calls.

Comment: It is as if the mock callout does not understand which context to run under on order change.

Comment: please  add code all code so one can easily reproduce this error and see what alternative solution one can provide you .Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I was able to resolve this issue after searching through multiple forums. This post guided me-[Unit tests that need more than one WebServiceMock](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19256/unit-tests-that-need-more-than-one-webservicemock)

Although the above link is for webservicemock and not httpcalloutmock, it guided me in understanding the issue.
I was using 2 diff Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, multiCalloutMockA);
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, multiCalloutMockB); for diff api calls from the 2 diff classes in my code. That is the reason why correct test context changed on changing the order.

I just removed one of them and mapped endpoint2test for diff api calls as mentioned below-
 endpoint2TestResp.put('https://api.statuspage.io/v1/pages/ac/incidents/unresolved.json',fakeResp1);

```
    endpoint2TestResp.put('https://service-now.com/api/now/table/incident',fakeResp2);


    HttpCalloutMock multiCalloutMock = new MultiRequestMock(endpoint2TestResp);



    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, multiCalloutMock);
```